# Jython not finding virtualenv packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, jython

When I do `pip freeze` I see `numpy` and `sklearn` in my `virtualenv`. When

My `runner.py` consists of :

```
from preprocess import Data

def main():
   pass
```

`preprocess.py`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
import numpy as np
```

I run `jython runner.py` I get the error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

Not sure why I can't find any of the packages I've installed.

Comment: what is output of `jython -m pip freeze`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov http://dpaste.com/1HKMMSA

Comment: do you activate your `virtualenv` in shell before executing command?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov yes